# PHP/SQL prepared statement with double quotes

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm using an HTML input element to accept data from a user and save it in a mySQL database.  To do this, I'm using PHP and mysqli to create a prepared statement.

This works very well until I try to accept an input string containing a double quote(").  If the input string contains a double quote, the data saved will be the string up to the double quote character.

For example:

I saw a 7'9" person.

Will be saved as:

I saw a 7'9

I've searched high and low, but can't find a solution.  I've tried mysqli_real_escape_string, but that just adds backslashes to escape meaningful characters.  When coupled with the prepared statement, the backslashes are interpreted literally and the double quote still interrupts the string.
So my example would be:

I saw a 7\'9

I even thought maybe the PHP wasn't getting the whole string from the input element, but when I echo the element's value, I do see the whole string.

Here is some example code.  I've removed some business details, but this is generally what I'm trying to do.

```
$sqlSave = $objConnection->prepare('update tbl set Answer=? where ID=?;');
$sqlSave->bind_param("si", $sqlAnswer, $sqlID);

$sqlSave->execute();
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, so please forgive my ignorance.  Any help or additional information is appreciated.

Comment: Whats the length of your column? Double quotes shouldn't have an issue with the code you're showing.

Comment: The column is VARCHAR(200).

Comment: The DB has it cut off at the double quote, or viewing it in a browser has it cut off? If you are outputting in an element like `input` the double quote is closing the `value` attribute.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, indeed it's something very obvious. Just look at the *generated HTML code* and you will immediately get a clue.

And then learn by heart that HTML attributes have to be **always** encoded using `htmlspecialchars()`

Comment: Thank you!  It was being saved in SQL correctly, but was cut off in the input element when I assigned the value.  htmlspecialchars() works fabulously!

Answer (score 0):

I was mistaken.  The PHP was saving the data correctly.  The data was cut off when it was displayed in the HTML input element.

Using htmlspecialchars() converted the " to `&quot;` and displayed everything.

Thank you to everyone for helping me catch this.